# linux: the first parameter of select

Tags: c, linux, sockets, select

```
int select(int nfds, fd_set *readfds, fd_set *writefds, fd_set *errorfds, struct timeval *timeout);
```

For the first parameter `nfds`, here is what I get from wiki:

> This is an integer one more than the maximum of any file descriptor in
>   any of the sets. In other words, while adding file descriptors to each
>   of the sets, you must calculate the maximum integer value of all of
>   them, then increment this value by one, and then pass this as nfds.

I have a simple question:
If I have more than one socket to process, how should I set the first parameter of `select`?

Should I set it with the largest socket number + 1?

If so, does it mean that the `select` is listening all of file descriptors which is less than the largest socket number + 1?

For example, I have three sockets: 111, 222 and 333. If I set the first parameter as 334, does it mean that I'm listening all of file descriptors from 0 to 333?

Comment: seems like a duplication of an old post:
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7742/whats-the-purpose-of-the-first-argument-to-select-system-call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I set it with the largest socket number + 1?

Yes!

> If so, does it mean that the select is listening all of file
>   descriptors which is less than the largest socket number + 1?

No, it only performs its operations on the fd_sets that are listed in 
readfds, writefds, and exceptfds

> For example, I have three sockets: 111, 222 and 333. If I set the
>   first parameter as 334, does it mean that I'm listening all of file
>   descriptors from 0 to 333?

No, you are only doing $select$ on 111, 222 and 333.

Internally sys_select sets up 3 bitmaps which have a bit set to 1 for each of the three bitsets and then if any of these bits are set (which in turn corrospond the file descriptor operation) then the `wait_key_set` operation is performed on it.

The reason for this interface is that in the kernel it devolves into a very predictable for-loop; making it quite safe to work with; rather than trying to do the calculation internally in the kernel.